# GeoServer - Conversion formula between scale and resolution

Tags: geoserver, tiles, scale, resolution, gridsets

I am trying to figure out what is the conversion formula between scale and resolution used by GeoServer, specifically when creating a new gridset for Tile Caching. One would expect that the conversion formula for a given resolution expressed in **m/px** would be:

**ScaleDenominator = Resolution * (PPI / 0.0254)**

However, I have discovered that the following formula gives exactly the correlation between scale and resolution found in GeoServer:

**ScaleDenominator = Resolution * (90 / 0.0252)**

The value of 90 for PPI is understandable because you can find in GeoServer's documentation ([here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#format-options)) that

> The OGC standard output resolution is 90 DPI.

However, I can't understand the value 0.0252. From my point
of view there are 2 possibilities:

- Either there's a bug in GeoServer because 0.0252 is used for conversion between meters and inches, instead of 0.0254.
- Or GeoServer is correctly using a conversion ratio of 0.0254 between meters and inches, but it is using a PPI of 90.71428571428571, which doesn't make much sense to me either.

Can someone help with this? I am using **GeoServer 2.13.1**, and similar results have consistently been obtained when using different coordinate systems.

Comment: Check the code?

Comment: The scale formulas come from the SLD specification, check it out. Also mind, you've been discussing the scale denominator for projected coordinate systems, but there is a different one for geographic ones. Check out http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=1188 and http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=16700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/lite/RendererUtilities.java#L417) seems to indicate that GeoTools (and hence GeoServer) uses 0.0254 in the scale calculation.

```
public static double calculatePixelsPerMeterRatio(double scaleDenominator, Map hints) {
    if (scaleDenominator <= 0.0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The scale denominator must be positive.");
    double scale = 1.0 / scaleDenominator;
    return scale * (getDpi(hints) / 0.0254);
}
```

and unless you have set a hint for the DPI you will be [using 90.714](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/lite/RendererUtilities.java#L535) which is possibly to do with [US vs International Inches](https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/issues/1365).

```
public static double getDpi(Map hints) {
    if (hints != null && hints.containsKey("dpi")) {
        return ((Number) hints.get("dpi")).doubleValue();
    } else {
        return 25.4 / 0.28; // 90 = OGC standard
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton. Given that GeoServer uses a DPI of 25.4 / 0.28 when there's no hints, the conversion formula gets reduced to

**ScaleDenominator = Resolution * (1 / 0.00028)**